# What does regular expression \\s*,\\s* do?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am wondering what this line of code does to a url that is contained in a String called surl?

```
String[] stokens = surl.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

Lets pretend this is the surl = "http://myipaddress:8080/Map/MapServer.html"
What will stokens be?

Comment: it splits by "comma, which can be surrounded by 0 or more whitespaces"
. In your given string, there will be no splits.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That regex `"\\s*,\\s*"` means:

- `\s*` any number of whitespace characters
- a comma
- `\s*` any number of whitespace characters

which will split on commas and consume any spaces either side

Comment: Doubly-escaped backslashes in Java regexes are a royal pain.

Comment: @tom yeah - I particularly enjoy coding a literal baskslash in a regex: `\\\\ `

Comment: whats the difference between \\s and \s ?

Comment: @Lupos `\s` is regex for “whitespace”. To code a literal backslash in Java, you must escape the backslash with another backslash, so to code `\s` in the regex, you must code `"\\s"` in your program.

Answer (score 16):

- `\s` stands for "whitespace character".
- It includes `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`. That is: `\s` matches a space( ) or a tab(\t) or a line(\n)
  break or a vertical tab(\x0B sometimes referred as \v) or a form feed(\f) or a carriage return(\r) .

---

```
\\s*,\\s*
```

It says zero or more occurrence of whitespace characters, followed  by a comma and then followed by zero or more occurrence of whitespace characters.

These are called short hand expressions.

You can find similar regex in this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: The [`Pattern` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) says that the full match for `\s` is `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`, not just `[ \t\r\n\f]`.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierGrégoire. Updated the answer.