# I want to extract specific information from XML input using Hadoop Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Expected output is: `(Hadoop definitive guide,Tom white,24.90)`.

I have tried using the `Regex_Extract()` function. But, no luck yet. Can someone please help me out?

The input to my script is:

```
<CATALOG>
<BOOK>
<TITLE>Hadoop DEFINITIVE GUIDE</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>TOM WHITE</AUTHOR>
<COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CLOUDERA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>24.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>2012</YEAR>
</BOOK>
<BOOK>
<TITLE>Programming Pig</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>Alan Gates</AUTHOR>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Horton Works</COMPANY>
<PRICE>30.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>2013</YEAR>
</BOOK>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: What is your Pig version? I guess Rank is available from Pig 0.9. The script, I have written works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extract `<TITLE>`, `<AUTHOR>` and `<PRICE>` separately and then join them together using `JOIN` operator.

Following script achieves that:

```
-- Load input 
A = LOAD '/input.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (f1:chararray);

-- Extract <TITLE>
B1 = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(f1, '<TITLE>(.*)</TITLE>', 1) AS (title:chararray);
C1 = FILTER B1 BY title is not null;
D1 = RANK C1;

-- Extract <AUTHOR>
B2 = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(f1, '<AUTHOR>(.*)</AUTHOR>', 1) AS (author:chararray);
C2 = FILTER B2 BY author is not null;
D2 = RANK C2;

-- Extract <PRICE>
B3 = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(f1, '<PRICE>(.*)</PRICE>', 1) AS (price:chararray);
C3 = FILTER B3 BY price is not null;
D3 = RANK C3;

-- Join 3 data sets
D = JOIN D1 BY $0, D2 BY $0, D3 By $0;

-- Eliminate the ranks
E = FOREACH D GENERATE $1 AS (title:chrarray), $3 AS (author:chararray), $5 AS (price:chararray)

dump E;
```

For the input mentioned in the question, I got the following output:

```
(Hadoop DEFINITIVE GUIDE,TOM WHITE,24.90)
(Programming Pig,Alan Gates,30.90)
```

Comment: ok i'm able to extract the individual data,but m not able to join the 3 datasets..getting an parsing error. Error org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt-Erroe 10000:Error during parsing. Encountered " " at line 1..also not able to execute the Rank cmd..still modifying the above commands a bit i'm able to extract dem...not able to join dem..what m i doing wrong..plz help...

Comment: B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT(x,'<TITLE>(.*)</TITLE>',1)) AS (title:chararray); i extracted the individual data..

Comment: Which version of Pig are you using? My version of Pig is 0.14. This script worked perfectly for me. I have even posted the answer I got by running the script in my setup. Can you check `pig --version`? Probably, your version of Pig does not support `Rank`. `Rank` function is supported from Pig 0.11 onwards.

Comment: i'm getting an identifier error for RANK command..ENCOUNTERED <IDENTIFIER> C1,was expecting "as",";"...do we have any substitute command for RANK...coz m den getting an error for the last Command..

Comment: I asked you, what's your Pig version? Can you please tell me that?

Comment: ya ryt ,i'm using version 0.8...this is what is being used in my class...so is der any other way out...code works fine till join cmd...last one gives me an error...i have to submit it today by 4...

Comment: OK. So, that's the problem. In 0.8 `Rank` function is not supported. Let me check, if I can modify the script. If find alternative, I will update the answer/

Comment: B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'<BOOK>\\s*<TITLE>(.*)</TITLE>\\s*<AUTHOR>(.*)</AUTHOR>[a-zA-Z\\s*\\S*]+<YEAR>(.*)</YEAR>[a-zA-Z\\s*\\S*]+'));
Dump B
hey i got the answer:but i'm having difficulty understanding the regex passed here of [a-zA-Z\\s*\\S*]+'

Comment: [a-zA-Z\\s*\\S*]+ means one or more occurrences of alphabets, whitespace and non-whitespaces. Check the links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750716/what-does-regular-expression-s-s-do and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377480/what-does-this-s-regex-mean-in-javascript

Comment: Please post your answer. It would be of help.